# PHP 7.0 - urlencode/urldecode not symetrical

Tags: php, urlencode

I save a web page edited by users in our app backend

in js : encodeURIComponent returns this

```
%3C!--%20saved%20from%20url%3D(0077)https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fw3css%2Ftryw3css_templates_gourmet_catering.htm%23about
```

in php : urldecode  returns this

```
<!-- saved from url=(0077)https:\/\/www.w3schools.com\/w3css\/tryw3css_templates_gourmet_catering.htm#about
```

so far so good....

now, when I fetch the data from the db and reencode it in php urlencode returns this :

```
%3C%21--+saved+from+url%3D%280077%29https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fw3css%2Ftryw3css_templates_gourmet_catering.htm%23about
```

so it ends up in JS beeing decoded with + all over the place :

```
<!--+saved+from+url=(0077)https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryw3css_templates_gourmet_catering.htm#about
```

1 - yes I could just replace the + but I feel I am doing something wrong

2 - why does encodeurl do that if it is not compatible with js decodeURIcomponent ?

regards

Comment: I just found out rawurlencode instead...admin, why cant I post an answer ?

Comment: Because it's a duplicate question that has already been answered variously.